# pdfoutput=1 can't replace pdflatex for auto-pst-pdf

Tags: pdftex, auto-pst-pdf

It is frequently mentioned that latex and pdflatex are the same program invoked with different defaults for the variable \pdfoutput (0 in the former, 1 in the latter case); see [What is the practical difference between latex and pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-latex-and-pdflatex/357).  A common advice to enforce pdflatex is therefore to put \pdfoutput=1 within the first 5 lines of the preamble (like http://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#pdflatex).  This fails for the first example using auto-pst-pdf on https://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)%
  \pscircle*[linecolor=cyan]{5}
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,gridlabels=0pt]
  \Huge\sffamily\bfseries
  \rput(-4.5,4.5){A} \rput(4.5,4.5){B}
  \rput(-4.5,-4.5){C}\rput(4.5,-4.5){D}
  \rput(0,0){auto-pst-pdf}
  \rmfamily
  \rput(0,-3.8){PSTricks}
  \rput(0,3.8){\LaTeX}
\end{pspicture}

% removed by poster: \includegraphics{foo}% can be foo.jpg or foo.png

\end{document}
```

compiles just fine with

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape minimal.tex
```

and yields the desired `minimal.pdf`.  Adding

```
\pdfoutput=1
```

before (or after) `\begindocumentclass[12pt]{article}` followed by

```
$ latex -shell-escape minimal.tex
```

or even

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape minimal.tex
```

fails with `No pages of output` and

```
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
entering extended mode

Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of minimal-autopp.dvi failed.
This warning occured on input line 124.


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Could not create minimal-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
This warning occured on input line 124.

-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
```

In either case, the corresponding log file minimal-autopp.log says

```
Package ifplatform Warning: 
shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

)
\c@app@runs=\count111

! Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
"shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
auto-pst-pdf will not work!
.

See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.134         Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
                                    %
You need to run LaTeX with the equivalent of "pdflatex -shell-escape"
Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.
```

So, it seems like the auxiliary pdflatex process which generates the minimal-pics.pdf is now missing the option `-shell-escape`.

PS: Adding the option [crop=off] to auto-pst-pdf as in [auto-pst-pdf Problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25922/auto-pst-pdf-problem) does not change anything (and I guess it shouldn't have worked in the first place if that would have been the problem).

Comment: Do _not_ use the statement `\pdfoutput=...` it can be done automatically by the system. Do you have Perl installed?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: arXiv's recommendation to put `\pdfoutput=1` within the first five lines suggests that they do some sort of preprocessing. This practice is definitely *not* recommended for normal document writing.

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, Perl is installed: `$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int`

Comment: did you looked into the logfile, there are some more messages?

Comment: @Herbert: I've added the "suspicious" part of the logfile to the original post.

Comment: As already said, you _cannot_ use `\pdfoutput=1`! It makes no sense here. Everything is ok with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`. And as you wrote it works fine for you

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for looking into this.  I am perfectly happy with the workflow via `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>`.  It would have been nice to have some shebang-like syntax within the file which specifies that it should be processed with pdflatex.  (We have many tex-files lying around and I'd prefer to spend as little time as possible determining whether it's supposed to be processed with latex or pdflatex.)

Comment: @zieglerk: that is not possible. When the file is open you cannot modify the shell escape feature, it's too late.

Comment: @Herbert: I think your last comment clarifies (and settles) the issue.  Would you care to turn it into an answer, so I can accept it and close the thread?

Comment: @zieglerk: done it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shell-escape` feature cannot be activated from within a source file.  When the file is open you cannot modify the shell escape feature, it's too late. This is a safe behaviour otherwise one could do any unsecure action.