# Upgraded from Texlive 2013 to 2014 and pstbarcode no longer works

Tags: pstricks, texlive, auto-pst-pdf, pst-barcode

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{http://www.kernel.org}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Is anything special required in tl2014 to continue using pstbarcode?

```
! Package auto-pst-pdf Error:"shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
auto-pst-pdf will not work!.
See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.... Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `pstbarcode` itself. It is the `auto-pst-pdf` package requiring `--shell-escape` enabled. You have to enable it manually by `pdflatex --shell-escape` or something similar on MiKTeX/Windows

Comment: After including the option, it still does not work: `Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: creation of mwe.pdf failed. Could not create mwe.pdf. Auxillary files not deleted. pspicture No.1 undefined...` This worked fine in 2013 TL.

Comment: This helped: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25922/37570 Used [crop=off] and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an installed version of Perl (http://activestate.com/perl/ or http://strawberryperl.com/) if you want to use the crop option, which already makes sense. Otherwise use

```
 \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

Or simply use `xelatex` then you do not need `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: I ended up using `[crop=off]` as xelatex is telling me that environment Forest is undefined and installing Perl would be frowned upon by the architects - this is a Microsoft shop :(

Comment: There is no environment `forest` in the above example! If you want to use that package then load it.

Comment: No Forest in the example, but I am using it in the actual file. It compiles with `pdflatex` and `lualatex` but does not compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: "Does not compile" is not a useful error description. I have no problem with `xelatex`

Comment: Like I said, compiling with `xelatex` ends with an error stating that environment Forest is undefined, while both `pdflatex` and `lualatex` compile that file fine.

Comment: then you are running another file and not the above example.

Comment: Of course I am not running the above example!